# Special case for constraints in GAMS

Tags: math, optimization, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, gams-math

I am trying to code the following inequality:

[image]

Where

[image]

So, I tried to code it in gams as follows:

```
constraint1(k,n)..rPower(sum(j,w(j)*power(((a(k,j))-y(n,j)),p)),(1/p))-e(k)=l=rPower(sum(j,w(j)*power(((a(k,j))-y(????????,j)),p)),(1/p))-r;
```

However, first, I am not sure about how to implement the t=!n part to these constraints. Actually n and t are from the same set. But for this constraint, t on the right hand side should never take the value of the n on the left hand side.

Second, I think the code is not correct either. When I check the gams output in the equation listings, I always get values way off even for the very small (a_kj-y_nj) values.

[image]

In this example, there are 4 w values, p=2, and largest a_kj-y_nj=0.5. However the output is like this.

Would appreciate if someone could help me out.

Full GAMS code:

```
Sets
k   sample number /1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12/
j   criterion /1,2,3,4/
n   class1 /1, 2, 3/
t   class2 /1, 2, 3/
nk(n,k) / 1.(1*4), 2.(5*8), 3.(9*12) /
tk(t,k) / 1.(1*4), 2.(5*8), 3.(9*12) /;

Table a(k,j)
    1   2   3   4
1   1   1   1   3
2   1   1   2   2
3   1   2   1   3
4   1   2   2   1
5   1   1   1   3
6   1   1   2   2
7   1   2   1   3
8   1   2   2   1
9   1   1   1   3
10  1   1   2   3
11  1   2   1   3
12  1   2   2   1;

Parameters p /2/;

Parameters r /0.000001/;

Parameters y(n,j);
y(n,j) = sum(nk(n,k), a(k,j))/sum(nk(n,k), 1);

Parameters m(t,j);
m(t,j) = sum(tk(t,k), a(k,j))/sum(tk(t,k), 1);

Variables
e(k)
w(j)
z;

Positive Variable
e(k)
w(j);

Equations
constraint1
constraint2
constraint3
objective;

objective..z=e=sum(k,e(k));
constraint1(k,n,t)$(ord(n)<>ord(t))..rPower(sum(j,w(j)*power(((a(k,j))-y(n,j)),p)),(1/p))-e(k)=l=rPower(sum(j,w(j)*power(((a(k,j))-m(t,j)),p)),(1/p))-r;
constraint2..sum(j,w(j))=e=1;
constraint3(j)..w(j)=g=0.00000001;

Model nonrobust / all /;
Option nlp=MINOS, limrow=100;

solve nonrobust minimizing z using nlp;

display z.l, e.l, w.l , m, y, a
```

Comment: Not so easy to read. That means it is better to simplify, even at the expense of extra variables and equations. Note that sparse solvers like sparse problems. However, I noticed that `constraint1(k,n)..`  really should be `constraint1(k,n,t)$(ord(n)<>ord(t))..`

Comment: Which part would you think is problematic? Do you think the following code would be inappropriate?  `constraint1..(k,n,t)$(ord(n)<>ord(t))..rPower(sum(j,w(j)*power(((a(k,j))-y(n,j)),p)),(1/p))-e(k)=l=rPower(sum(j,w(j)*power(((a(k,j))-y(????????,j)),p)),(1/p))-r;`

Comment: Never repeat expressions. So substitute out `D(k,n)/D(k,t)`.

Comment: Alright, I managed to overcome that issue. Thanks a ton for your guidance. Lastly, what would you say about the values I obtain. They are way off than their actual values. Do you think there is a problem with rPower, power, or sum functions? I added full code into the main post.

Comment: The GAMS model is a bit of a mess. Also `constraint1` is not the same as the mathematical description. Suddenly an `m` is appearing.

Comment: Yeah, I know it is a bit messy, I am a beginner at GAMS. However, I rechecked the code but constraint 1 seems the same to me as the mathematical description. I have defined m(t,j) which is exactly the same of y(n,j). I did it to use `$(ord(n)<>ord(t))` expression for the constraint 1. Do you think there is something wrong with the functions (sum, rPower or power)?